# How to write a proper algorithm for Maximum Subsequence Product

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array A, trying to solve the maximum sub-sequence
product problem algorithm. So the function should return the start and end indices of the **subsequence** that has the greatest product **using dynamic programming**. For instance:

```
funcSubSeqMaxProduct(A[1..n]) {

return j,k  #Where j<=k and A[j,...k]  is the maximum sub sequence product.

}
```

What I tried so far is:

```
funcSubSeqMaxProduct(A[1..n]) {
   for i = 1 to n
     pro(i) = max(ai, pro(i-1)*ai)
     j = max(pro(i))

    #something I am struggling how to get the correct indices of lower and upper bound.
    return j,k 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your values are positive, you can substitute them to their logarithms, and in the log-array search for max sub-array sum with [Kadane’s Algorithm](http://theoryofprogramming.com/2016/10/21/dynamic-programming-kadanes-algorithm/).